# Using config file in public class

Tags: xml, class, config

Is it possible to to load config file, that contains server connection, using class constructor and storing it in a public static string. For example,

Config.xml

```
<Config>
  <ConnString> "server=...; user id =...; user pass=...; database=...";</ConnString>
</Config>
```

Code:

```
namespace Connection.Settings
{

public class Settings
{
    public Settings()
    {
    XmlDocument cfg = new XmlDocument();
    cfg.Load("Config.xml");
    connection = cfg.SelectSingleNode("/Config/ConnString").InnerText;

    }


    public static string connection;
    public string Connection
    {
        get
        {
            return connection;
        }
    }

    public static string ConnectionString = connection;
}
}
```

The reason for doing this is that connection could be shared by many apps and yet I could easily change the connection in xml file without any need to touch the applications.

Comment: I strongly suggest you learn how configuration works in .NET.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's possible.  AppConfig is probably the most common place to store connection strings but it's not required.  As long as all your applications can access the file you want to store it in it could be used as a common source for different configuration settings.

I didn't try your code example but something like:

```
var conf = XDocument.Load(filenamehere.XML);
var connection = (from c in conf.Decendents("Config")
                  select c.Element("ConnString")).SingleOrDefault();
```

should recover the setting from your XML.